# Perl search file recursive for string and replace

Tags: perl

in terminal with perl how can I search all php files starting recursive from current working directory for a single or multiline pattern like:

```
<script>var a=''; * hamoorabi.com * </script>
```

*Read like:* find all between `<script>var a='';` and `</script>` but only if contains `hamoorabi.com` and replace it with an empty string (remove it).

As it´s javascript code there can be a bunch of unescaped characters inside the search string.

Comment: what part of this is recursive?  finding the files?  talk more about how to find the files you want to change, and show what you've tried and where you've gotten stuck

Comment: the files I´ve edited my question ;)

Comment: the replacement part of this is like `my $beginning = '<script>var a=\'\''; my $end = '</script>'; my $containing = 'hamoorabi.com'; s/\Q$beginning\E(?:(?!\Q$end\E).)*\Q$containing\E.*?\Q$end\E//g;` (untested)

Comment: what operating system?

Comment: It´s Debian 3.2.73-2+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: What do you mean by *"search file recursive for string and replace"*? Do you want to treat lines in the file for paths to be processed? Do you want to process all files with a similar name in the same way? Please show what you tried and describe carefully how it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a unix or cwygin prompt:

```
$ find . | grep .php | xargs ./xx1.pl
```

Where perl script xx1.pl is :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

undef $/;
for (@ARGV) {
        open(FILE,$_);
        my $content = <FILE>;
        close(FILE);
        my $beginning = '<script>var a=\'\'';
        my $end = '</script>';
        my $containing = 'hamoorabi.com';
        #$content =~ s/(<script>.*?)(hamoorabi.com)(.*?<\/script>)/$1$3/sg;
        #much better regex provided by ysth
        $content =~ s/\Q$beginning\E(?:(?!\Q$end\E).)*\Q$containing\E.*?\Q$end\E//gs;
        open(FILE,">$_");
        print FILE $content;
        close(FILE);
}
```

Comment: thanks! this looks really clean and nice unfortunately it does only replace hamoorabi.com not the whole string meaning `<script>*.*</script>` can this be done?

Comment: ahhh think before you read. `$content =~ s/(<script>.*?)(hamoorabi.com)(.*?<\/script>)//sg;` should do it ;)

Comment: this will get rid of scripts that don't contain hamoorabi.com too (if there is a later hamoorabi.com in the file) and other stuff after them.  see my comment to the question for a better regex.

Comment: I've updated my answer with regex provided by ysth, tested OK.

Comment: Please don't use global file handles if you can help it, especially not *twice* for different files. If your input files are in `@ARGV` then you should just use `<>` with no need for explicit `open` or `close`. `local $/ = undef` or just `local $/` is far better that `undef $/`. ***Always*** make sure that *every* `open` call succeeded as, without them, letting your program continue to run makes no sense. *Always* use the three-parameter form of `open`. Use the `/x` modifier and add spaces to regex patterns that are even slightly complex.

Comment: More thoughts: It's ***Cygwin***! Please use as many blank lines as necessary in your code to help to explain your thought process. Don't read entire files into scalar variables unless you have a damn good excuse (possibly into arrays, but also rarely). *Never* use trivial bash command-line utilities if you are invoking `perl` anyway. That, thank God, is it, I think.

Comment: Oh, and use narrative to *explain* your code. *"From a unix or cwygin prompt"* and *"Where perl script xx1.pl is :"* say nothing about the reasons for your decisions or explain what you have written. In general, it is pretty much pointless to just get a program "working". It's always vastly more useful to write something that is visible and comprehensible, and explains the design so that any one of your team can pick it up, understand it, and make it work with very little effort.

Comment: no need for grep or lengthy code, just `find -name '*.php' | perl -pi -0777 -e's/<script>var a=\x27\x27;(?:(?!<\/script>).)*hamoorabi\.com.*?<\/script>//gs'` (untested)

Answer (score 0):

Use [File::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find) to walk a directory tree looking for files.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

sub wanted {
  # Ignore anything that isn't a file
  return unless -f;
  # Ignore anything without a .php extension
  return unless /\.php$/;

  # Your filename is in $_. Your current directory is the 
  # one which contains the current file.
  # Do what you need to do.
  open my $fh, '<', $_ or die $!;
  ...;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is also helps use further more.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

> String replacement `Regex` forms

```
my $str = "<script>var a=''\; * hamoorabi.com * </script>";
$str=~s#<script[^>]*>((?:(?!<\/script>).)*)<\/script># my $script=$&;
$script=~s/^(.*)hamoorabi\.com(.*)$/$1$2/g;
($script);
#esg;
print $str;
```

> Replace the content on the same file using `Tie::File`

```
my @array;
use Tie::File;
tie @array, 'Tie::File', "Input.php" || die "blabla";
my $len = join "\n", @array;
@array = split/\n/, $len;
untie @array;
```